# In JavaScript, removeChild node error when removing an element from its parent

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a method to remove an item from a list when its checkbox is checked. The 1st item is removed fine, but when I want to remove the subsequent items I get this error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

But according to my code it look like I'm doing the right thing. Can you tell me what is missing, please?

HTML:

```
<ul class="category-list">
  <li class="product-item">
    <article class="product-item__wrapper">
      <h1>
        <label for="product_item_1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_1" id="product_item_1">
          Product Item
        </label>
      </h1>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li class="product-item">
    <article class="product-item__wrapper">
      <h1>
        <label for="product_item_2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_2" id="product_item_2">
          Product Item
        </label>
      </h1>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li class="product-item">
    <article class="product-item__wrapper">
      <h1>
        <label for="product_item_3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_3" id="product_item_3">
          Product Item
        </label>
      </h1>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li class="product-item">
    <article class="product-item__wrapper">
      <h1>
        <label for="product_item_4">
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_4" id="product_item_4">
          Product Item
        </label>
      </h1>
    </article>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
import utils from 'utils';

class CategoryList {

  constructor() {
    this._categoryLists;
  }

  init(component) {
    this._categoryLists = document.querySelector(component);
  }

  _deleteItem() {
    let categoryList;
    let productItems;
    let productItem;
    let productItemInnerWrapper;
    let checkboxes;
    let checkbox;

    for (categoryList of this._categoryLists) {
      checkboxes = categoryList.querySelectorAll('.product-item__checkbox');

      for (checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          productItem = utils.findParent(
            checkbox,
            'product-item'
          );

          productItemInnerWrapper = 
            productItem.querySelector('.product-item__wrapper');

          productItemInnerWrapper.classList.add('product-item__wrapper--animate');

          productItem.classList.add('product-item__item--animate');

          setTimeout(() => {
            categoryList.removeChild(productItem); // --> This produces an error. I don't know why
          }, 500);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export default CategoryList;
```

Comment: Well, you didn't provide an example of your DOM structure, nor of the methods you're calling, so I don't know what you're hoping us to do. The error message isn't lying to you; the `productItem` must be a ***child*** of the `categoryList`. Not a more deeply nested descendant.

Comment: Interpreting your method names, It even looks like `productItem` might be an *ancestor* of `categoryList`, which definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh, also, you're doing this in a `setTimeout` callback, and for some reason, though you used `let`, you didn't scope it to the loop, which is the whole point of `let` being added to the language. So you have the usual *"closure in a loop"* problem here.

Comment: your class name starts with `.` ? here `'.product-item__warpper--animate'`

Comment: What's the benefit of the `setTimeout` in the loop anyway? They'd still all be removed basically at the same time. Were you trying to stagger them by a half second?

Comment: Thanks all, for your responses. The actual codebase is long so I shortened and simplified it for the sake of StackOverflow, hence the spelling mistakes. But I've corrected them now.

Comment: OK, that's a bit more helpful. So again, this is basically the "closure in a loop" problem. By the time your `setTimeout` callbacks run, the loop has ended. And because the `productItem` variable is scoped *outside* the loop, it's referencing only the *last* assignment of that element. Therefore, you're calling `.removeChild` with it several times. It'll likely work one time, but after that, that one element has been removed, so trying to remove it again causes the error.

Comment: ...if you got rid of `setTimeout` it would work better. Otherwise, declare your variables at their first point of use, like `for (let categoryList of this._categoryLists) {`, instead of grouping the declarations at the top of the function. Also: `let productItem = utils.findParent(`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks for your tips. I had to use `setTimeout` as in the real code there're some animation that happens before the item is removed. But it works after putting the `let` inside the loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, but you don't need a separate `setTimeout` for each element in the loop. I would wrap all the code in that function in a single `setTimeout`. Then when it runs, there's no async code happening per-iteration, which was part of the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution which should work everytime is getting the `parentNode` directly from the element you want to remove:

```
productItem.parentNode.removeChild(productItem);
```

Comment: `productItem.remove()` with a polyfill if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.